# How can I solve an ODE when $F(x_0)=F'(x_0)=0$ is given at an unknown point $x=x_0$ using bvp5c?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, mathematical-modeling

I'm attempting to solve the following ODE using MATLAB bvp5c. I've used bvp5c for other typical multipoint boundary value problems but I have no idea how to deal with ODEs with conditions given at an unknown point x0.

$(1-\phi)(x-C)+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2x^2F''(x) + rxF'(x) - rF(x) = 0$
where $F(x_0) = F'(x_0) = 0$, $x_0$ is unknown.

I guess I should make use of the parameter in bvp5c (to solve for f(x) and x0 together). Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The usual strategy for a second order equation
$$
\partial _{x}^{2}f(x)+a(x)\partial _{x}f(x)+b(x)f(x)=c(x)
$$
is to set
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{1}(x) &=&f(x), \\
f_{2}(x) &=&\partial _{x}f(x)
\end{eqnarray*}
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{x}f_{1}(x) &=&f_{2}(x), \\
\partial _{x}f_{2}(x)+a(x)f_{2}(x)+b(x)f_{1}(x) &=&c(x),
\end{eqnarray*}
or
\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{x}f_{1}(x) &=&f_{2}(x) \\
\partial _{x}f_{2}(x) &=&-a(x)f_{2}(x)-b(x)f_{1}(x)+c(x)
\end{eqnarray*}
or
$$
\partial _{x}\left(
\begin{array}{c}
f_{1}(x) \\
f_{2}(x)%
\end{array}%
\right) =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1 \\
-b(x) & -a(x)%
\end{array}%
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
f_{1}(x) \\
f_{2}(x)%
\end{array}%
\right) +\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
c(x)%
\end{array}%
\right)
$$
or
$$
\partial _{x}\mathbf{f}(x)=\mathsf{A}(x)\mathbf{f}(x)+\mathbf{g}(x).
$$
Now let
$$
\partial _{x}\mathsf{U}(x,y)=\mathsf{A}(x)\mathsf{U}(x,y),\;\mathsf{U}%
(x,x)=1.
$$
Then
$$
\mathsf{U}(x,u)\mathsf{U}(u,y)=\mathsf{U}(x,y),
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{f}(x)=\mathsf{U}(x,x_{0})\mathbf{f}(x_{0})+\int_{x_{0}}^{x}dy\mathsf{%
U}(x,y)\mathbf{g}(y)
$$
Thus, if you can obtain $\mathsf{U}(x,y)$ in some way, you have the solution
for any $x_{0}$

Comment: Thank you so much, I should have tried to solve it by hand first! Much appreciated.

Comment: One question: according to my calculation,
$\mathbf{f}'(x)=\partial_xU(x,x_0)f(x_0)+U(x,x)g(x)=A(x)U(x,x_0)f(x_0)+g(x)$
So how do we show that the last one is actually equal to 
$A(x)\mathbf{f}+\mathbf{g}(x)$, in other words $U(x,x_0)\mathbf{f}(x_0)=\mathbf{f}(x)$?

Comment: From the second term there is also a contribution due to the x-dependence of U(x,y), which gives A(x) times this term. This, togrther with A(x)U(x,x_0)f(x_0) leads to the correct expression.